# php get date in my timezone

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to php. I was able to get the time but the problem is it's in different time zone. What I want is to get the time in my timezone. Here's my code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC+8');
$mydate=date('h:i A');
?>
```

The codes above gives me the wrong time, my timezone is UTC+8. Example my time is 9:00PM, but the codes above returns 1:00PM. How could I fix this? Any help would be so much appreciated.

UPDATE: I got it working now (thanks to @enenen). My new code that returns the correct timezone in my area:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$mydate=date('h:i A');
?>
```

Comment: @Koren I live in the Philippines.

Comment: You can use 'Asia/Manila' for the Philippines. http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: oh God thanks so much @enenen. I got it working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

Answer (score 1):

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8'); works for me i'mm from the Philippines and Asia/Manila doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Timezone ID '`UTC+8`' is invalid. It is a notice from `PHP` engine, if your error reporting is excludes notices, this is the reason not to see it. You shoud use something like '`Asia/Manila`'. See documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).